# How to set up a network printer on NETGEAR router?

Tags: printing, netgear

I spend a day searching for a solution on how to access the ReadySHARE printer on NETGEAR R7000 router but I cannot found out the solution. It works well on windows 10 and Mac with the software provided by NETGEAR. Also, the printer works when I directly connect the printer to my ubuntu computer.

#### Router

```
Router Model            : NETGEAR R7000
Firmware Version        : v1.0.7.2_1.1.93
Router IP               : 192.168.1.1
Printer Server IP       : Don't see any IP on router setting webpage for connecting the printer
Connection with Printer : USB
```

#### Printer

```
Printer : Fuji Xerox DocuPrint P205 b
```

I can find my printer under the `Network Printer`.
[image]

But after the configuration, I cannot print a test page.
[image]

#### Printer Properties

[image]

Is it unsolvable currently?

Comment: Is the printer currently attached to the router and working correctly with other devices on the network? Can you look in the router's administration pages and see the printer's IP address? What make and model printer is it? Please edit your question to add these details.

Comment: If you go to ADD PRINTER, then either FIND NETWORK PRINTER or WINDOWS WITH SAMBA, does it show up there? You may have to give it a SMB path to your router. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1):

Why messing up with the Router for setting up a Network printer ?

Well by default, dhcp will be enabled in your router. So connect you network printer, assign a static private ip, subnet and gateway referring to your router configuration  in the printer. Most of the network printers will have the option to set it. Now you can add the network printer in the system connected to the same network for default printing.

*Note : Here I asked you to assign static IP for printer even if router setting is DHCP because this will help your network printer to have a same IP always.*

Oh Well if its a USB printer, then also u don't need to mess with the router. Just connnect your usb printer to your system running Ubunut, install the driver while promting. After installation in the dashboard search for **printers** then add your usb printer and while adding you can choose to share the printer or not, choose yes. That's it.

If driver installation doesn't pops up then you need to install **cups** and follow the step. [Click here and follow](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/step4/cups/local.html)

Comment: This is a USB printer, not a network printer. Cheers, Al

Comment: If you add the printer as a local USB device, and share it out, the computer will need to remain on for his other computers to print. He's using the routers READYSHARE so that ANY computer should be able to print to the device. Cheers, Al